# How to add column Unit to @Header per every row have Flag Allow 1?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I work on a query for SQL Server 2012. I have an issue: I can't add column unit to `@Header`.

When row in the temp table `#nonparametric` has the flag `Allow` set to 1, it must have two columns per unit .

Here I have flag allow set to 1 per family and parametric so it must statement of `@Header`.

have parametricUnit,familyUnit because I have Flag Allow =1 for parametric and family on temp table

on #nonparametric temp table .

with another meaning on table #nonparametric I will get all DKFeatureName have Flag Allow 0 will have one

column but DkFeatureName have Flag Allow =1 will have Extra column per Unit it Names will be column + 'Unit' on variable @Header .

```
create table #nonparametricdata
(
PART_ID nvarchar(50) ,
CompanyName  nvarchar(50),
PartNumber nvarchar(50),
DKFeatureName nvarchar(100),
Tempvalue nvarchar(50),
FlagAllow bit
)

insert into #nonparametricdata
values
('1222','Honda','silicon','package','15.50Am',0),
('1900','MERCEIS','GLASS','family','90.00Am',1),--have column per Unit on @Header because FlagAllow=1
('5000','TOYOTA','alominia','source','70.20kg',0),
('8000','MACDA','motor','parametric','50.40kg',1),--have column per Unit on @Header because FlagAllow=1
('8900','JEB','mirror','noparametric','75.35kg',0)

create table #FinalTable
(
DKFeatureName  nvarchar(50),
DisplayOrder  int
)

insert into #FinalTable (DKFeatureName,DisplayOrder) 
values 
('package',3),
('family',4),
('source',5),
('parametric',2),
('noparametric',1)
```

what I try is below :

```
DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @Header = STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME (DKFeatureName)
            FROM #FinalTable
            ORDER BY DisplayOrder
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,2,''
    )
    select @Header
```

Expected Result is :

```
[noparametric], [parametric],[parametricUnit], [package], [family],[familyUnit], [source]
```

Comment: can you please see this issue on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480447/how-to-build-select-query-split-temp-value-to-two-column-one-per-number-and-anot  because this issue on link based on current topic that solved for me

Comment: really I'm sorry I write link of another post here because another post depend on current post so it will not take too much time to understand so ok I accept that

Comment: Clearly you're not understanding me.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a hack, but by using a JOIN and a simple CASE

**Example**

```
DECLARE @Header NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT
    @Header = STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ', ' + quotename(A.DKFeatureName) + case when B.FlagAllow = 1 then ','+quotename(A.DKFeatureName+'Unit') else '' end
            FROM #FinalTable A
            Join #nonparametricdata B on A.DKFeatureName=B.DKFeatureName
            ORDER BY DisplayOrder
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ),1,2,''
    )
    select @Header
```

**Returns**

```
[noparametric], [parametric], [parametricUnit], [package], [family], [familyUnit], [source]
```

EDIT.

You may want to change

```
Join #nonparametricdata B on A.DKFeatureName=B.DKFeatureName
```

to

```
Join (Select distinct DKFeatureName,FlagAllow 
       From #nonparametricdata 
     ) B on A.DKFeatureName=B.DKFeatureName
```